# How did medieval peasants decide where to build their houses?

Tags: middle-ages, early-medieval, europe

When a person moved out of their parents' house, they needed a house. How was it decided where this house would be located? For example, did they just pick the next available spot on a path? Were there peasant level political considerations? Were there coveted house locations? If so how were these conflicts resolved?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: I don't have research to back it up, but my impression is that they didn't move out of their parent's house. The [nuclear family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_family) is a modern invention; pre-modern families lived together in a multi-generational household.  (I believe Wikipedia understates). Peasants usually didn't have the right to own land or houses.  It may be worth your while to research [Assart](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/assart), which is generally illegal unless done by the landowner/lord.

Comment: Having made the two comments above, I want to add that this is an intriguing question. I like questions like this that examine assumptions about the past, and that provide an opportunity to study how to study history.

Comment: Part of the issue is our assumed definition of peasant.  The feudal system as we commonly reference it started in the 9th century, leaving 500-800 as viable ground for 'free-roaming peasants'. (But as such we would have no historical records about them.) But in England at least this corresponds with the Anglo-Saxon period, and they had their own word for peasants: slaves. (they did have a middle class however, freemen.)  Question still suffers from generality. 500 year time span and every political division in 'Europe'.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to provide evidence of prior research, since googling doesn't leave a great trail. I can modify the question to avoid "moving out of parents' house" if it makes the question more clear.

Comment: @justcal 's comment that we don't have any records seems consistent with what I have seen. I am prepared to accept that there might not be an answer

Comment: There is quite a bit of information *for some areas and times*, but 'Europe' covers too much territory to try to narrow down an answer. Check the question on [medieval villages](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/63326/16951) from earlier in the week. By giving a specific date and nation/ethnicity, the user provides enough information that specific history could be referenced. Some of those sources might help you as well.

Comment: There is a Wikipedia page about it here. But I have gave up trying to turn it in to an answer. Answer would probably suit a lawyer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peasant_homes_in_medieval_England